# I am making a focus pomodoro but i have a problem in click buttons, they are not interact and do not know more what can i do

Tags: button, timer, onclick, click, countdowntimer

Here I will leave printouts of the code that may be useful[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoXXc.png)[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prhxY.png)][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUtC5.png)[here I execute the function in the main file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boQbr.png)

I would like that when I click on the buttons they produce background music, but they don't even display the message on the console.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZg2i.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.